# Поиск по сайту, проблемы с MySQL (или руками)

Tags: mysql

Есть страница. На ней и обработчик и форма. Задача вывести результаты поиска если найдены совпадения со строками в БД (MySQL 5.7.30)

Весь код с комментариями

```
<?php
// ловин значение инпута
$looking_for = filter_var(trim($_POST['looking_for']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

// Функция подставляющая значение в запрос
function looking_for()
    {
    global $pdo;
    global $looking_for;
    $sql_looking_for = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM `shop` WHERE `Main_title` LIKE "'.$looking_for.'" '); 
    return $sql_looking_for;
    }

// Вызываем функцию
$sql_looking_for = looking_for();
```

?>

HTML:

```
    <section class="container">
    <h1 class="main_h1_page">Результаты поиска</h1>
    <form  method="post">
        <input type="text" name="looking_for" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <div class="results_of_search">
        <?php foreach($sql_looking_for as $one_res): ?>
        <div class="one_finded_item">
            <?php echo $one_res[2] ?> <!-- [2] колонка содержащая заголовок -->
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</section>
```

Теперь к сути проблемы. В БД есть несколько строка, искомая колонка Main_title содержит "Плюсы продуктового магазина". Ожидаю, что при вводе одного слова, к примеру "продуктового" в цикле выпадет нужный результат, однако результат выпадает лишь в случае 100% совпадения со строкой в БД.

Как добиться желаемого результата?

Comment: Используйте INSTR() / LOCATE() вместо LIKE. И учтите, что некоторые символы требуют квотирования - так что лучше перейдите на подготовленные запросы (`pdo->prepare`). А то SQL injection - просто дело времени...

Comment: @akina спасибо, про безопастности не переживайте, это в коде есть) когда программа станет рабочей, поставлю заглушку и подготовленный запрос) Спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать)